# spring boot project not build due to frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm using spring boot 2.3.0 version and Java 11. I'm using com.github.eirslett.frontend-maven-plugin.1.6 for my project for react stuff. But now from some time I'm not able to build my project and getting some build errors which I've mentioned below.

Error:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn run build) on <project>: Failed to run task
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
```

My pom.xml looks like this

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>frontend</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and yarn</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v16.12.0</nodeVersion>
                            <yarnVersion>v1.22.19</yarnVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
<!--                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>-->
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I've tried many ways but I'm not able to fix this. Please provide me any soluition regarding this.

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Comment: Please include the complete error traceback.